# Call AppleScript from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, applescript, itunes

Is this possible?

I want to modify song tags in iTunes from the extension.

Comment: If you have shell access from Chrome extensions, you can use the `osascript -e` command to evaluate AppleScript. Otherwise, I doubt that it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call applescript or execute shell commands directly from chrome.  However, a clever workaround is to start a web service on your computer that listens for web requests, and build an extension that calls this service.  An example for something like this in action is the [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) extension which uses a Ruby background service.

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't really make sense to do in my case, so I guess I'm going to have to take a different approach.